# Saving the name of a instance of a class in a string variable

Tags: python, maya

I have this strange question that im stuck for days. I'm developing a small program using python for maya. (By now I hope you know I'm not a professional programmer. just a side coder to build some internal scripts and tools)

The tool I am building has a lot of UI elements I am creating as classes, which have their own methods.

What I need to do, is to pass an instance of such a class, using a string. I know this is strange and pls let me explain.

I need to implement a drag and drop operation of a widget class, which can pass a message from the source to the destination. the message always gets forcefully (by Maya) gets converted into a string!!!

```
Class a(object):
    def __init__(self, v)
        self.v=v

instance=a("important")
```

normally what I can do is

```
print (instance.v)
```

but what happens is during the message exchange process, the instance gets converted to text and I get a string instead of the python object

> '<**main**.a object at 0x000001BB0696CA90>'

which is a string,. and i can't run or query any methods in the actual function..

I know this is very noob. Please advice on how I can convert a class instance saved in a string to a python object so I can call up its methods or query variables..

Thanks again.

Comment: what happens if you write `self.value = v`

Comment: yes. my mistake on the question. fixed it. but still the problem still remains!

Comment: Did you try to serialize and de-serialize the instance of class using Pickle?

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: i want a way to covert a string which has the name and memory location of the instance into a variable i can actually call on the methods!! From '<__main__.test_class object at 0x000001BB0696CA90>' to a new_instance.v

Comment: Pickeling worked!! thank you @KiranBaktha

Answer (score 0):

How about writing a method for your class which returns the string?

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v

    def getV(self):
        return self.v
```

Result:

```
>>> Instance = A('important')
>>> print(Instance.getV())
important
>>> Instance.getV()
'important'
```

If that doesn't work maybe you could write a `printV()` method...

Answer (score 0):

Well.. pickeling worked!! i just wanted a way of creating a string from an instance and using the string to make the reference to the instance again.!! thanks, @kiran Baktha!

i just did

```
beforetransfer = pickel.dumps(instance)
```

and at the recieving end

```
aftertransfer = pickel.loads(beforetransfer)
```

thanks community!! you guys are amazzing!!